# jQuery UI Autocomplete with ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to get the jQuery Automcomplete thing to work, but it wont do as i want :P
This is my code:

JavaScript:

```
        $("#CustomerID").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/customer/search",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(c) {
                            return {
                                label: c.Company,
                                value: c.ID
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                alert('Select');
            }
        });
```

ASP MVC:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult Search(string term)
    {
        if (term == null)
            term = "";

        List<JSON_Customer> customers = repCustomer.FindCustomers(term).ToList();
        return Json(customers);
    }

    public class JSON_Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }

    public IQueryable<JSON_Customer> FindCustomers(string searchText)
    {
        return from c in _db.Customers
               where c.Company.Contains(searchText)
               orderby c.Company
               select new JSON_Customer
               {
                   ID = c.ID,
                   Company = c.Company
               };
    }
```

I get the request from `$.ajax` and I return the correct list of customers according to the search term. And the `success` method is invoked. I can see that `data` has a `[object Object]` value but what do I do next? No customers drops down in my list. I'm using the `response($.map...` code from the http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp but it just wont work.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Can you use a diagnostic/debug tool such as Firebug (plugin) for FF, Developer Tools (F12 for IE or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for Chrome) to see exactly what is returned to the browser, and how it's treated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this before my first AJAX request -- I bet it will help.  Defines the standard items and takes care of the "d" attribute microsoft puts in as the top level attribute.

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: "{}",
     dataFilter: function(data) {
        var msg;

        if (typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined' && typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function')
           msg = JSON.parse(data);
        else
           msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
           return msg.d;
        else
           return msg;
     }
  });
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! It did the trick, and now everything is working. I had to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` though, since when I had it on the `term` was `null` inside `Search(string term)`.

Comment: You're welcome.  This was originally written to work with ASP.NET 2.0 -- it might be the newer DLLs don't need the contentType... not sure about that.